# Alembic/SQLAlchemy after_create not triggering

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm working on a project where I need to attach some custom triggers to a table that's defined using SQLAlchemy, and controlled using Alembic.

Right now, I have a simple loop that attaches a `after_create` event to each declarative table class:

```
trigger_on = [
    Series,
    Tags,
    Genres,
    Author,
    Illustrators,
    AlternateNames,
    Translators,
    Releases,
    Language,
    Covers,
]
def iife_capture(func, param):
    def callee(table, connection, **kwargs):
        return func(connection, param)
    return callee

for classDefinition in trigger_on:
    event.listen(
        classDefinition.__table__,
        'after_create',
        iife_capture(create_trigger, classDefinition)
        )
```

Effectively, I'm defining an immediately invoked function to capture the passed parameters, that returns a function that calls `create_trigger` on the table `classDefinition`. This part actually works fine, and if I manually execute `create_all()`, everything is fine.

However, if I create the table via alembic, the `after_create` calls don't seem to be actually called.

The other SE question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629037/how-do-i-get-alembic-to-emit-custom-ddl-on-after-create) looks to actually be describing a similar issue. I tried attaching the events to `sqlalchemy.Table`, rather then the individual tables, but it wound up causing them all to execute after only one table was created, which fails because the `create_trigger` function specifically attaches things to the table it's called against.

How can I call a function after the creation of each table (or all the tables, either could work)?

Basically, I want to be able to do my complete DB setup just by using alembic, rather then the horribly messy apparatus I have now.

Comment: @Flake have you managed to solve this?

Comment: @JasonRussell - Nope!

Comment: Hi @Flake, I am not sure what you are using your triggers for, but I was palnning on using them to populate history tables for various models. I found a great solution and I just thought you may be interested in it https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-continuum

Comment: @JasonRussell - Interesting. I'll have a look. Incidentally, who is "@Flake"?

Comment: @Flake is the misread name of Fake, who's name is in any case Fake.